# Select row with max date between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that have some similar fields:

table 1:

```
id  contact_id |fit_date    | model
---|-----------|------------|---------
1  | 10        | 04/03/2009 |Platinum   
2  | 10        | 12/01/2010 |Platinum
5  | 12        | 10/03/2019 |Gold
```

table 2:

```
id  contact_id |fit_date    | model
---|-----------|------------|---------
1  | 10        | 06/14/2018 |Platinum   
2  | 10        | 07/25/2016 |Platinum
5  | 12        | 01/28/2008 |Gold
```

I need to somehow return the row from the combined tables that has the highest fit_date where the contact_id = '10' for instance.

I need something like this:

```
id  contact_id |fit_date    | model
---|-----------|------------|---------
1  | 10        | 06/14/2018 |Platinum
```

Then later when I query WHERE contact_id = 12 I would need this:

```
id  contact_id |fit_date    | model
---|-----------|------------|---------
1  | 12        | 10/03/2018 |Gold
```

I'm completely lost on this query and am unsure how to begin.

Comment: Store dates as dates. The see about rows holding the groupwise max on a column.

Comment: While this doesn't help with your question, I have to ask why you have 2 tables with the same schema? The best long term solution (potentially not possible depending on the system you are working on) may be to merge the data of those two tables into 1 table and have a type field if they are two types of the same kind of entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.contact_id = 10
union all
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where t2.contact_id = 10
order by fit_date desc
limit 1;
```

If you have an index on `contact_id, fit_date` in each table, then this might be more efficient:

```
(select t1.*
 from table1 t1
 where t1.contact_id = 10
 order by fit_date desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select t2.*
 from table2 t2
 where t2.contact_id = 10
 order by fit_date desc
 limit 1
)
order by fit_date desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

seems  you need  the max for the united  tables

```
select   max(fit_date), model , contact_id
from  (
  select id , contact_id ,fit_date,model
  from table1 
  union 
  select id , contact_id ,fit_date,model
  from table2
) t 
group by  model , contact_id
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  Gordon Linoff would work perfectly.  It makes sense.  Also,  dmoore1181, I took your advice and merged both tables into one.  Thanks again.